# How can I determine if STDERR is buffered on a linux box?

Tags: java, linux, unix, buffer, pipe

I have a java app that calls a ksh script that is hanging. A look on the backend shows that the script's write process to `STDOUT` is full and blocked. `STDERR` is supposed to be empty and my java code is reading that first. Debugging shows the java app hangs reading the `STDERR` inputstream which in turn causes the script process attempting to write more to STDOUT to become blocked. I think `STDERR` is being written to second(after `STDOUT`), so it just waits until it sees input(and it can't receive input because write is stuck on `STDOUT`).

This app works fine on multiple Linux boxes(all identical OS and kernels) except for one. Putting each inputstream read in separate threads resolves the issue on this one box. I know the linux default for `STDERR` is nonbufferring and that input usually is written to that immediately. So I'm thinking that `STDERR` might be set to buffered on this box. How/Where do I find the value of that?

Comment: Hmm, I might have found it in stdio.h

Comment: Have you found the answer? could You post it here?

Comment: Nope, never figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Reading stderr and stdout with a single thread is a *bad* idea, case in point.  the *correct* solution is to use two separate threads.  anything else is just a race condition waiting to fail.

maybe you are confusing non-buffering with non-blocking?  making stderr non-buffering will not remove the possibility that your program could hang at any point in time (by blocking on stderr or sdout).

Comment: Oh yeah, I see why it is a bad idea to use one thread now. I was just wondering why the read worked fine without any issue on 4+ boxes but failed on one box. All having the same OS and kernel, I figured it was some configuration/setting. Characters from STDERR's outstream should be available immediately for reading when it is non-buffering. Since the read from stderr was hanging, I figured the output was not available immediately(and it was buffering).

Comment: @JohnSmtith - thus is the nature of race conditions.  they work great "most" of the time, then... boom!  no rhyme or reason.